# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on menu

Tags: javascript, menu

Trying to implement a responsive menu. 
added script  which is as follows

```
    (function() {

    var bodyEl = document.body,
        content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
        openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
        closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
        isOpen = false;

    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents() {
        openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( closebtn ) {
            closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

        // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
        content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
                toggleMenu();
            }
        } );
    }

    function toggleMenu() {
        if( isOpen ) {
            classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        }
        else {
            classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        }
        isOpen = !isOpen;
    }

    init();
})();
```

and the markup includes the neccessary classes and buttons. 
For some reason I am getting Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on the openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );. Javascript rookie and haven't been able to solve this.

Any suggsestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the element is not there in the DOM when the script is executing.  You will need to call the init method after the DOM has initialized.

Move the script to the bottom after the body tag.  or use jquery and call your init method inside `$(document).ready()`.

Also, consider moving the variable initializations to the init method

```
    bodyEl = document.body,
    content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
    openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
    closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' )
```

so that they read the proper values after the dom is loaded, instead of when the script is initialized.