# Hide dropdown menu upon clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue with the dropdown menu that I've implemented in a React App.

The dropdown is based on this article: https://blog.campvanilla.com/reactjs-dropdown-menus-b6e06ae3a8fe

Opening & closing the dropdown works fine the dropdown, however when I click on a button in the menu, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null
```

I went back to the blog and have seen that other people have reported the same error in the comments:

> *Nice one. But just the last part doesn’t work. dropDownMenu stay ‘null’*

One possible solution was to add `current` to the following line of code:

#### original version

`if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {`

#### modified:

`if (!this.dropdownMenu.current.contains(event.target)) {`

I found a similar answer here on StackOverflow where another user was having a problem with a dropdown menu: [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297573/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null-on-menu) but I still can't figure out the error.

## InnerHeader.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from '../images/logo.svg'
import Settings from '../lotties/Settings'

class InnerHeader extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
    
  this.state = {
    showMenu: false,
    fade: false
  };
  
  this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
  this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
}


showMenu(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
  });
}

closeMenu(event) {
  if (!this.dropdownMenu.current.contains(event.target)) {
    
    this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });  
    
  }
}
 
handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
    this.setState({
      currentUser: null
    })
    this.props.history.push("/")
  }

render() {
    return (
        <>
        <div id="inner-header">
          <div className="logo">
            <Link to="/dashboard"><img src={logo} height="50px" alt="site logo" /></Link>
          </div>
          <div>
        <button 
          className="menu-button"
          onClick={this.showMenu}>
          <Settings/>
        </button>
        <br />
        {
          this.state.showMenu
          ? (
            <div
            className="drop-down fade-in"
            ref={(element) => {
              this.dropdownMenu = element;
            }}
            >
                <div className="center-it-menu">
                <Link to="/account">  Account </Link>
                <br />
                <Link to="/integrations"> Integrations </Link>
                <br />
                <Link to="/tutorials"> Tutorials </Link>
                <br />
                <Link to="/support"> Support </Link>
                <br />
                <button id="menu-alert" onClick={this.handleLogout}> Logout </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
              )
            }
      </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(InnerHeader)
```

Since I'm still learning to program, I don't want to rely on a library for this task or just c&p a solution. Other than a solution, I'd like to know what's causing this and how to fix it since it. Since it's one of the first articles displayed when you google **react create a dropdown menu**, if anyone else tries to implement this I'd like them to have a good answer to it to.

Comment: Refer to the section on callback refs in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). You need to define ```this.dropdownMenu```  on your class component in your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say, ref attribute in described scenario is not needed at all. To have your menus collapsed upon clicking outside of them, you can make use of [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method which will traverse down the DOM tree to find element with `className="menu"` among `event.target` ancestors:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM

class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
    };
    
    this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
  }
  
  showMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }
  
  closeMenu(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest('.menu')) {
      
      this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
      });  
      
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.showMenu}>
          Show menu
        </button>
        
        {
          this.state.showMenu
            ? (
              <div
                className="menu"
              >
                <button> Menu item 1 </button>
                <button> Menu item 2 </button>
                <button> Menu item 3 </button>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render (<Card />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue and thank you for linking to the documentation about ```Element.closest``` for me to read up on.

Comment: @RHBlanchfield : you're most welcome, aside from above optimization tutorial you're referring to seems to have plenty of room for further improvements, at least in what is related to click handling stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you don't click on **Button** then this code is not executing and not initiate **this.dropdownMenu** hence it is **Undefined**. In such cases, you should use **onChange** event and add a listener to it and do whatever you want in that function. May it will help you.