# How to fix React useRef Hook bug when clicking outside of container with ref attribute?

Tags: reactjs

I have span element with click event on it, which task is to open dropdown mobile menu by toggling the state.

```
<span onClick={() => setMobileNavState(!isMobileNavOpen)}>X</span>}
```

At the same time I have ref for that mobile menu container to handle closing of that same menu when clicking anywhere outside of it.

```
const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavState] = useState(false);
const mobileNavRef = useRef();
useOnClickOutside(mobileNavRef, () => setMobileNavState(false));
```

I am passing mobileNavRef variable to child component MobileNavigation as a prop ( that is where I render that mobile menu ) and also isMobileNavOpen which I use for toggling css class ( open or closed )

```
<MobileNavigation isMobileNavOpen={isMobileNavOpen} mobileNavRef={mobileNavRef}/>
```

This whole code by now belongs to parent component which is holder of the state and ref logic.

And finally I have child component  with this mobile menu container with ref attribute

```
return (
        <div className={`mobile-navigation ${isMobileNavOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}`} ref={mobileNavRef}>
            <div className="mobile-navigation-sidebar">

            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Now my problem is that when I click "X" element for opening mobile menu it opens, which is good, but when I click it again, once, for closing it closes and then opens again very fast. I think it is some kind of state bug or something, or because "X" which is outside of the mobile menu ( which is the area when clicked should close mobile menu ) and at the same time it is used for opening that menu. Can anyone see what the problem is, or help me out with this.

Comment: Simply [don't use Refs for that purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60657270/11299053), it's not the recommended use case anyways

Comment: Try adding `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event object in the span that closes the menu.

Comment: Maybe this will do the trick, right, thanks!